# Interpretation of hotthreads in elasticsearch

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I am facing high IO waits in my elasticsearch cluster across all the nodes while indexing documents.
From some post online I learned about hot threads in elasticsearch. I collected output of hot thread APIs.
please see below output :

```
55.0% (275.1ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[01][refresh][T#1]'
     7/10 snapshots sharing following 24 elements
       java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
       java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)       org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterFlushControl.waitForFlush(DocumentsWriterFlushControl.java:272)

53.6% (267.8ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[01][bulk][T#1]'
     3/10 snapshots sharing following 37 elements
       sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.force0(Native Method)
       sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.force(FileDispatcherImpl.java:76)
       sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.force(FileChannelImpl.java:388)
       org.elasticsearch.index.translog.TranslogWriter.syncUpTo(TranslogWriter.java:272)
       org.elasticsearch.index.translog.Translog.ensureSynced(Translog.java:521)
```

Other than refresh_interval (30s) all the other configs are default.
From the above output of hot threads, can someone explain what makes my ES nodes to wait so long. I understand that first thread says its waiting for flushing and 2nd one for translog, 
Which config tuning should i try for?
Note: I am using UPDATE operation for indexing my documents and document updates are frequent.

Answer (score 0):

During updates, Elasticsearch needs to "commit" it's data to make it searchable (initially it's written to Translog and later it's flushed to segments of index. Commit operation in Elasticsearch is heavy operation for IO/CPU. Usually, during heavy updates operations you want to do commit as rare as possible.

Parameter which is involved in this is called `index.refresh_interval`

> How often to perform a refresh operation, which makes recent changes
>   to the index visible to search. Defaults to 1s.

You should try to find balance between doing frequent updates - good for data visibility and doing it less frequent to maintain performance. You could try to set  it up to `1m` or something bigger. Ideal value depends a lot on your use case

Comment: Thanks @Mysterion, I can always try that, can you suggest about any other param? what if we try to increase index_buffer_size? Will that help to increase throughput?

Comment: Default value is 10% of allowed heap, so what would be more good idea is just to try and increase heap size, however, I doubt it will change behaviour much